# DropdownlistFor...show/hide div depending on what is chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I got this dropdown list fectching some choice from a db

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Choosen, new SelectList(Model.test.Select(k => k.ChoosenTest)))
```

The dropdownlist contains 2 choices for the user. In my view I also got two different divs and 
I would like to show/hide the divs corresponding to the choice the user have made in the dropdown WITHOUT submitting the form. Is there a way to do this?

You could say that i would like the dropdown to behave like a button where the choice
the user make could trigger an onclick-function. Thanks!

EDIT: Found a similar qustion, now its looking like this:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Choosen, new SelectList(Model.test.Select(k => k.ChoosenTest), new { @class = "dropdown1" }))
                        <br />

                        <div>
                            <select class="dropdown2">
                                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                                <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
```

Here is the jquery:

```
$(function () {
        $('.dropdown2').css('display', 'none')
    });

    $(".dropdown1").change(function () {
        $('.dropdown2').toggle();
    });
```

The jquery seems to work beacuse it hides dropdown2 onload..
The rest does not work though, have I given the dropdownlist the class="dropdown1`" in the right manner?

EDIT 2:

I messed upp giving the dropDown its class:
This seems to be the right way:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Choosen, new SelectList(Model.test.Select(k => k.ChoosenTest)), new { @class = "dropdown1" })
```

Just moved the class one step to the right...

Comment: -1 what have you tried so far?

Comment: I dont really know where to begin? Is it possible to make the 
dropdownlist behave in such a way?

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery it should be pretty easy -

```
<div>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#div1").hide();
            $("#div2").hide();

            $("#choosen").change(function () {
                if ($("#choosen").val() == "one") {
                    $("#div1").show();
                    $("#div2").hide();
                }
                else {
                    $("#div2").show();
                    $("#div1").hide();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <select id="choosen">
        <option value="---">---</option>
        <option value="one">One</option>
        <option value="two">Two</option>
    </select>

    <div id="div1">Div 1</div>
    <div id="div2">Div 2</div>
</div>
```

And output would be kind of -

[image]